# How to set Content-Type:application/json in ui5 oData.read() ?

Tags: sapui5

When I call `XSet/$count`, I found the response is in xml, which is hard to parse.

I tried to call

```
oModel.read("/XSet/$count", {
    urlParameters: "$format=json",
    filters: [new Filter(this._oFilterState.aTaskFilter, false)],       
});
```

called`XSet/$count?$format=json&$filter=(status eq 'NOT_STARTED')`

returned

> "System query option '$format' is not compatible with the return type."

But `XSet/$count?$filter=(status eq 'NOT_STARTED')&$format=json` can return a json format error response.

I want to try the second way, which is change `Content-Type: application/xml` to `Content-Type: application/json`. But failed to find this in API: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/read

Comment: What do you get when you call the URL `http://host:port/path/XSet/$count` directly in your browser? It should NOT be XML but an actual number: http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers/$count?$filter=City%20eq%20%27Berlin%27

Comment: Hi @Marc, yes, it returned number when success, but I'm doing error handling for this call, it returned xml format response when failed. I've asked my backend colleague, he let me try to change `content-type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model.read method requests for an XML response by setting the Accept header as

> Accept:application/atom+xml,application/atomsvc+xml,application/xml

However the count request is a plaintext response. You could get the count in two ways, one would be setting the Model's payload to use json and the other way would be a jQuery AJAX call.

You could initialize the model with a json parameter set to true.

```
var oModel = sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("Service_URL",{
   json:true
});
```

This would pass a header with Accept:application/json